# Using repl.it databases locally

Tags: replit

I have used repl.it database on the official website. But now I want to use it offline/locally. I have installed replit from the `PyPi` library. But using it with `from replit import db` command doesn't work. It raises a `NoneType` exception. Is it possible to use them on a local machine for storing data? If yes please let me know!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: All info available here: https://docs.replit.com/misc/database

### Summary

It is possible to access a replit database locally by using the URL from an active repl. This URL can be discovered using the `REPLIT_DB_URL` environment variable. However this changes every time a repl is restarted and even from time to time whilst a repl is active. Therefore it can't be used robustly.

In order to robustly use a repl's db locally, you must make the database accessible using a proxy which allows you to connect from a URL which doesn't change. An example script can be found here: https://replit.com/@util/Replit-Database-proxy